# Product to Sales-Rep Mapping for Demo purposes

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, field-mapping

Scenario: Company XYZ's Products are varied & complicated, as a result one single Sales Rep cannot be proficient in knowing about all the Products. Therefore a single Opportunity is mapped to multiple Sales-reps (Each sales Rep specializes in one Product). Core Sales  Rep remains the Opportunity Owner,but a Product Specialist works on the opportunity.

*Action:* The moment the Sales Rep (Opportunity Owner) adds a product to an Opportunity the Specialist-Rep gets automatically added to Opportunity Split.(As the Product is already mapped to a particular sales Rep in the background). **Question:** How Easy/Difficult is it to configure Product-To-Sales Rep Mapping? Can it be done via a simple configuration?*(**Note:** I am a Business Analyst, my configuration skills are limited to Business-User level, I deal mostly with customers & Partners)*
***Desired Result:*** The moment the Product to which mapping is done at the background is added to an Opportunity, the sales rep (Product-Specialist mapped to the Product) gets automatically added to Opportunity Split on the Opportunity related list.
Can the above be achieved by Customer-Success Consultants like me, or it HAS to be dependent on Developers? Please advice. Would like to try this Product mapping in my developer Org for Demo purposes.

Comment: If it is one rep per product then add a lookup to user on the product page. The you can write logic to put that rep in the split. Makes it easy to modify later if needed too.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. For writing the Logic I guess I have to depend on the Developer. The first part is easy. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there no work around to achieve this ? Do I HAVE To depend on a Developer to write a Trigger/ Code?? I am not a Developer. it's disappointing that whatever I want to design requires C.O.D.I.N.G. Is there no other workaround via Configuration? I know the answer is "NO" but still trying against odds..

Comment: you might be able to do it with process builder if you link each product to a rep. When you start getting into logic of what if oli is removed then what do you do, it gets more complicated.  But, add a prod specialist field to the product as a lookup to user then start playing with PB in insert of oli. Lots of gotchas though and should really be resolved by well written code that handles all the what ifs and make management of the mappings easy without additional code updates.

Comment: Process Builder is a good option.As you rightly said there are a whole lot of gotchas.Ex:Think of a company such which has 700 Products;Mapping every single Product would mean those many PBs? And you're SPOT-ON when you talk about the Logic "what if Oli is removed & replaced by Sam". For now, for my Demo purposes will use PBs but a well-written Code to handle exceptions / regression Testing & Negative scenarios will have to wait as it requires a Developer which I am not. Right now, I'm  trying to design something on my own without dependencies. Thanks for your inputs @Eric! Appreciate it !!

Comment: you would only need 1 PB that uses the lookup on the product to get the rep. Don't need 700 of them. While you may think it is a simple ask, as you build up all the requirements you will see it can become quite complex